# Merge two properties together in ramda.js

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this:

```
var books = [
   { 
      title: 'Some Book',
      author: {
         firstName: 'John',
         lastName: 'Doe'
      }
   },
   {
      title: 'Another Book',
      author: {
         firstName: 'Jane',
         lastName: 'Smith'
      }
   }
];

var getNames = R.pipe(
   R.prop('author'),
   R.props(['firstName', 'lastName']),
   R.join(' ')
);

console.log(R.map(getNames, books));
```

So basically, I am trying to get the full names by combining two properties together. This works, but I was wondering if there is a better (shorter) way to do this in `Ramda`? I went through the documentation, but there are some functions that I don't quite understand the usage of, yet. So that's why I am asking here.. :)

fiddle:
https://jsbin.com/jidiwejatu/edit?js,console

------------------- EDIT -----------------

This is rather a simple example, but if I had to merge properties from different paths, that's what becomes more complicated I think, since I would have to use `R.path` to get to each property. Am I right?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `juxt` (Added in v0.19.0) to get array of anything you want from object:

```
var getNames = R.pipe(
    R.juxt([
        R.path(['author', 'firstName']),
        R.path(['author', 'lastName'])
    ]),
    R.join(' ')
);
```